# Windows Phone 7 programming the use of the USB port

Tags: windows-phone-7, usb

I would like to make a Windows Phone 7 application that takes advantage of it's USB port to communicate with the PC.  I would like to write an application to control or push information/data to the PC from the application.  But I am having problems finding information on where to start.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction with some resources?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to communicate over the USB connection is over HTTP.

To get this to work you'll need:
- a webservice hosted on the PC you're connecting to.
- a way for the app (on the phone) to know the hostname of the PC. (You'll probably need to enter it manually)

When you have these it should be straight forward.

Comment: I like it. Maybe add some Bonjour/ZeroConf stuff http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf and you could be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you want to make sure to push data to a client PC, you will have to use a kind of synchronization by using the internet. For example create a wp7 application and a desktop application and let them sync the data based on a user object or anything like that.

As far as I know also the updated SDK for Mango will not support programming against the USB dataconnection.

Comment: There is something about ... when someone says something is impossible.  ;-)

Comment: That's true, hoping you have a way around this issue? ;)